# how to get reference to color attribute defined in xml layouts?

Tags: android

Update: There were 2 custom attributes defined in CustomTextView.. If both are defined in xml it works fine.. If first is missing it does not give any value for 2nd also...

```
<com.mycompany.projectname.MyCustomView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:extraColor="?someColor"
/>
```

Here someColor is another color attr which varies for different themes..
I need value of extraColor custom attribute in MyCustomView class...

Currently obtaining it as below:

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,  R.styleable.CustomTextView, defStyleAttr, 0);
```

a.getColorStateList() does not work here...

CustomTextView defined as:

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomTextView">
        <attr name="state" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="extraColor" format="reference|color" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Update: There were 2 custom attributes defined in CustomTextView..
If both are defined in xml it works fine.. If first is missing it does not give any value for 2nd also...

Comment: Did you try "a. getColorStateList(R.styleable.CustomTextView_extraColor)" ?

Comment: a. getColorStateList(R.styleable.CustomTextView_extraColor); works good.. But only if both custom attributes are defined in xml..

Answer (score 1):

Could you try that one..

```
a.getColor(R.styleable.CustomTextView_extraColor, Color.WHITE)
```

Answer (score 1):

use only either *reference* or *color*

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomTextView">
        <attr name="extraColor" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

And then if it is reference get it like,

```
a. getColorStateList(R.styleable.CustomTextView_extraColor);
```

if it is color then,

```
   a. getColor(R.styleable.CustomTextView_extraColor, Color.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have said, it looks like the naming is inconsistent (copy+paste error?):  in most of the code you posted, your refer to a `CustomTextView`, but in the XML, you use `MyCustomView`.

Try changing your XML:

```
<com.mycompany.projectname.CustomTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:extraColor="?someColor"
/>
```